# Can Blender video editor speed up a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a mp4 video that plays 3 FPS and I want to speed the FPS up to 24 FPS.  Can I do this in Blender 2.8 video sequencer?  When I use the Video Sequencer Speed Control, with Speed Factor 1, Multiply Speed 8, "Use as speed" checked, it just plays the video still at 3 FPS, but for every one frame it plays, it skips the next 8 frames; I want to play every frame but play it at a faster rate.

Comment: If you make a new file, set your render settings to 24fps, and just import the mp4, the frames are then adjusted by itself if I remember correctly. I dont think u have to mess around with speed factor.

Comment: Wow that worked.  Thanks so much.

Comment: no problem :) much luck!